# Create groups based on survival

Tags: r, survival

I have survival data from about 100 patients. I would like to divide my cohort into 2 groups: a group of 50% of the best surviving patients and a group of 50% of the worst surviving patients. How do I do this?
Thanks

Alex

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. Please see here hwo to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.